# Logrotation is not rotating logs each day

Tags: linux, rsyslog, syslog

I am new to log rotation and have a syslog server that have been setup to recieve firewall logs over 514.
Now, the firewall is generating A LOT of data, ~600-800GB/day and the servers capacity is 1TB.
Im trying to remove the logs after 24hours with logrotation.

All logs go into /var/log/syslog

I am using rsyslog and trying to make the rotation work
In my `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` I have the following lines

```
{
        rotate 1
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
        rotate 1
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}
```

In my `/etc/logrotate.conf` I have configured it as shown

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
daily

# use the adm group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root adm

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 1

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
#dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

Now after ~30-36 hours, there's only 100GB left in space on the server and the logs have not been deleted.

What exactly am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the config you provided complete? None of the config entries applies to `/var/log/syslog` and the first block in `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` is useless.

You have a config to rotate many files in `/var/log` once a week and a config block to rotate once a day which is used for nothing.

You probably want to add `/var/log/syslog` at the top of your `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`.

You should be able to use `logrotate --debug --verbose /etc/logrotate.conf` to test your configuration.

With your logrotate config (once the `/var/log/syslog` is added to the first block). It should copy/rotate the existing logfile once a day to `syslog.1`. The compress options are rather useless here. Because of `delaycompress` the first rotation is not compressed and from `rotate 1` no `syslog.2` to compress later will appear.

What you more likely want is `rotate 0` (the `compress` options could be removed). From the man page:

> *rotate count*
>
> Log  files  are  rotated count times before being removed or mailed to the address specified in a mail directive. **If count is 0, old              versions are removed rather than rotated.**

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add the line /var/log/syslog at the top in the thread.
However, it says it was rotated today 00:00 but the /var/log/syslog file is still around 600GB, so the file has not been removed. When rotated daily, shouldnt the syslog file be removed fully?

Comment: The `logrotate --debug ...` will only show what it would do and not actually rotate anything. That nothing happens is strange (just in case you missed that detail). For your config it should at least rotate the existing `syslog` to `syslog.1`. See also my additions to my answer.